# Here-document with two variables

Tags: variable, for, here-document

Trying two variables with a here-document to generate a list of bash scripts. I ran into the problem that I cannot put the two variables into the script properly and the output file (only one file) has the file name of `cut_cat.sh`, basically the code is interpreted cat as text, not a function. How can I improve this?

This is in the bash shell environment. The operating system is Red Hat Linux.

The input file `R2_adaptor` contains `Sample_ID:CGATATTCG` (the first half is sample ID and the second half is the sequence to be removed). They are separated by `:`.

```
    for n in cat ${FA_PATH}/R2_adaptor;
  do first=$(echo $n | cut -d ":" -f 1) 
  second=$(echo $n | cut -d ":" -f 2) 
  cat <<- EOF > ${SCRIPTS}/cut_${first}.sh
    #!/bin/bash
    
    FA_PATH="/home/xxx/test_files"
    
    cutadapt -a TTCCTCCT -A echo ${second} --cores=14 \
    -o ${FA_PATH}/${first}_R1_trim.fastq.gz \
    -p ${FA_PATH}/${first}_R2_trim.fastq.gz \
    ${FA_PATH}/${first}_R1_001.fastq.gz ${FA_PATH}/${first}_R2_001.fastq.gz 
    
    
    EOF
    done
```

Here is an example of the  `${FA_PATH}/R2_adaptor` file

```
Sample2:AGAAGTTT
Sample3:TTGGATAT
Sample4:GTAGTATT
Sample5:ATATATAT
Sample6:AACTTGGC
Sample7:GATGGTGA
Sample8:GTCCCTAT
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some context. What language are you writing in? Is the outer script supposed to be a shell script too? What operating system are you using? `for n in cat ${FA_PATH}/R2_adaptor` means "iterate over the string `cat` and the value of the variable `${FA_PATH}/R2_adaptor`. Did you mean to iterate over the contents of a file instead?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I edited the post. there are two `cat` in the code, the second one doesn't seem to be interpreted?

Comment: There is only one `cat` and yes, that is treated as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of this is guesswork since you haven't told us any detail at all, but I *think* that `${FA_PATH}/R2_adaptor` expands to a file name and I *think* what you are trying to do is iterate over the contents of the file. Which means that what you were probably looking for is `for n in $(cat  ${FA_PATH}/R2_adaptor)`.

However, and although that would work here if you just have one string per line, [it is better](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) to get used to using `while` loops for things like this.

I am, again, guessing that your input file has two strings separated by `:`, something like:

```
ACTTGCTATAGCGAT:CGATATTCGGCGATAT
```

If so, you can do:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

FA_PATH="/home/xxx/test_files"
SCRIPTS="/path/to/scripts"

while IFS=: read -r first second rest_if_any_ignored; do
  cat <<- EOF > "${SCRIPTS}"/cut_"${first}".sh
#!/bin/bash

cutadapt -a TTCCTCCT -A '${second}' --cores=14 \
 -o '${FA_PATH}/${first}_R1_trim.fastq.gz' \
 -p '${FA_PATH}/${first}_R2_trim.fastq.gz' \
 '${FA_PATH}/${first}_R1_001.fastq.gz' 
 '${FA_PATH}/${first}_R2_001.fastq.gz' 
EOF
done < "${FA_PATH}"/R2_adaptor
```

Note that I also removed the `echo` from `-A echo $second` since the `echo` would just be a string there and the `-A` expects an adapter sequence to remove.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand your logic. And yes -A will remove a string. The `R2_adaptor` file itself contains `Sample_ID:CGATATTCGGCGATAT` (the first half is sample ID and the second half is the sequence to be removed). I would like to have both information used in the code and I think your code does that. However, after putting this into the terminal, it doesn't exit the editing mode and I had to ctrl+C to exit out. And no scripts were generated. I wonder if there is something I am missing..

Comment: Thank you, Stéphane for editing the script. I still have the same issue that I cannot exit out of the editing environment.

Comment: @Molly_K probably something _I_ am missing, not you. Can you please edit your question and add an example "${FA_PATH}"/R2_adaptor file so I can see what's really there?

Comment: @Molly_K actually, please try again with the updated answer. And make sure you copy it exactly: the `EOF` needs to be the first thing on a line by itself.

Comment: thank you very much for your edits and it worked like a charm. Sorry I was away for two hours and just had a chance to check back.

Comment: @Molly_K you're welcome and please, no reason to apologize! We all have lives :) By the way, you might also be interested in our sister site, [bioinformatics.se].

Comment: I did not notice the existence of "Bioinformatics". I am signing up now!!! Thank you for the information!

Comment: @Molly_K you're welcome, us bioinformaticians need to stick together! :P